# File transfer over VPN on VirtualBox

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, rsync

I'm accessing a computer inside a VPN via SSH. This access is being done through a VM.

If I wanted to do file transfer and was in an actual machine inside the network I would do `rsync from/path/filename username@hostname:to/path/`. Although, on the VM, my machine has a name like filipe@filipe-VirtualBox, and doing rsync with that user and hostname doesn't work. Is it possible to transfer the files from the remote machine inside the VPN to my VM? If not through rsync, what's the easiest way to transfer them?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what it is that fails. If it's just the hostname that doesn't resolve, you can use the IP address of the target machine instead of the name: `fillipe@10.20.30.40` If there is a different issue, can you please elaborate on where it's failing?